# I don't understand what exactly a command with find does

Tags: bash

I have a command written in my notes, but I can't figure out what exactly it does. Can you please help me?

Here it is:

`find / f1 -exec ls -l {} \;`

It searches for the file f1 in the root directory and executes ls -l, but the files from which directory will ls-l show and what the end mean -  `{} \;`?

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: type `info find` into your shell in order to read the documentation about find.

Comment: Thank you, sorry for the duplicate :S but I can't delete it now.

Comment: you can use `-name` option to search for filenames.

Comment: Technically, that command should be executing `ls -l` for every file it finds under `/`, *and* any files under a directory `f1` in the current working directory, unless the space between `/` and `f1` is unintentional.

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand it now. I wasn't quite sure about the role of `f1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the notation `{}` means: insert filename here.
`\;` is end of `-exec`

Your man page should have told you so.